# Calculate poygon area in km2 from degrees to km2 in R

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, area

I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311812/turning-degrees-into-square-kilometres-km2) but I think it is possible.

I am trying to calculate the area in Km2 of a polygon given by the vertices in degrees:

```
library(pracma)
x= c(-40.03953, -44.24278, -40.90583, -35.55361) #those are geographic coordinates
y= c(-16.03372, -15.12306, -11.55778,  -6.78000) ##those are geographic coordinates

polyarea(x,y)

[1] -23.0599
```

But I need the resuts in km2. I think if I multiply |-23.0599| by 12343 (because one degree ~ 111.1 km) I will get an appoximate value in km2. But I am wondering if there is some more accurate way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd approach this as follows using `{sf}`. According to `?st_area`, great circle distances are computed when using geodetic coordinates:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

x <- data.frame(x = c(-40.03953, -44.24278, -40.90583, -35.55361),
                y = c(-16.03372, -15.12306, -11.55778,  -6.78000))

p <- st_as_sf(x, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = "epsg:4326") |> 
  dplyr::summarise() |> 
  st_cast("POLYGON")

a <- st_area(p)
a
#> 279915149252 [m^2]

# conversion #1
as.numeric(a) / 1000000
#> [1] 279915.1

# conversion #2
units::set_units(a, km^2)
#> 279915.1 [km^2]
```

Or you could make use of `st_transform()` in order to continue with a projected reference system if you do not want to use great circle distances.